# Problem uploading to Arduino Yun

Tags: arduino-yun, uploading

I have an Arduino Yun. I am trying to upload the code in Arduino but after I click on Upload, I get the error message shown in the image.

At first it showed the Arduino Yun under the port tab, after this message no Arduino is showing in port tab.
[image]

The portion of the error visible in the image:

> Couldn't find a Board on the selected port. Check that you have the correct port selected. If it is correct, try pressing the board's reset button after initiating the upload.

Comment: It's very hard to read that error, perhaps you could crop it a bit? It's also useful to include the message as text so that it's searchable for anyone else with the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In the Arduino IDE, click on `Tools` (on the menu bar). Then, open the submenu `Board` and make sure "YUN" is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you havent chose the appropriate serial port.

Under tools, you'll also find serial port - make sure the appropiate one is selected.